# Servlet web.xml authentication for welcome page

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, web.xml

I have a web.xml which looks like:

```
<web-app>

<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Default</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Index page</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
...
```

We want to deny access to resources by default, and specify the resources we want to allow access to.

If a user goes to **http://localhost:8080/** they get access denied, however, if the go to  **http://localhost:8080/index.jsp** it allows them in.  Both URLs should show the same page, and both should be allowed.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the thing to do will be to specify `/*` to catch the default, and do specific patterns like `/somethingElse.jsp` to catch any other pages that are *not* index.jsp. Hopefully your top level "directory" isn't very cluttered.

Comment: I'm gonna take that statement, print it out in big letters, frame it and hang it up by my desk :)